# The SearchContext of the locator object cannot be null Parameter name: locator

Tags: c#, selenium

I am having this issue while running this simple test. Although I have initialized the page, I'm still getting `null` error in `SearchContext` of `locator`.

**PropertyCollection.cs**

```
namespace automation2
{
    enum PropertyType
    {
        Id,
        Name,
        LinkText,
        CssName,
        ClassName
    }

    class PropertyCollection
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**EAPageObject.cs**

```
namespace automation2
{
    class EAPageObject
    {

        public EAPageObject()
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(PropertyCollection.driver, this);
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "TitleId")]
        public IWebElement TitleId { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Initial")]
        public IWebElement TextBox { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Save")]
        public IWebElement Button { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
namespace automationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        { }

        [SetUp]
        public void initialize()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://executeautomation.com/demosite/index.html");
            Console.WriteLine("Opened the browser");
        }

        [Test]
        public void ExecuteTest()
        {
            EAPageObject page = new EAPageObject();
            page.TextBox.SendKeys("Hello World");
            page.Button.Click();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void cleanup()
        {
            driver.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Browser is now closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "this issue"?

Comment: The static driver in the PropertyCollection class is not initialized.

Comment: @Grasshopper how to initialzie it kindly add your code